# Best way to access table instances when using SQLAlchemy's declarative syntax

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

All the docs for SQLAlchemy give `INSERT` and `UPDATE` examples using the local table instance (e.g. `tablename.update()`... )

Doing this seems difficult with the declarative syntax, I need to reference `Base.metadata.tables["tablename"]` to get the table reference.

Am I supposed to do this another way?   Is there a different syntax for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` recommended when using the declarative syntax?  Should I just switch to the old way?

Answer (score 10):

well it works for me:

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__   = 'users'
    __table_args__  = {'autoload':True}

users = Users()
print users.__table__.select()
```

...SELECT users.......

Comment: Note it is ____table____ NOT ____tablename____

Answer (score 4):

via the `__table__` attribute on your declarative class

Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion between **table** (the object) and **tablename** (the name of the table, a string). Using the **table** class attribute works fine for me.